# Unable to install the Application file in MacOS

Tags: postgresql, errors, error-log

I'm getting this error while installing PostgreSQL "The application cannot be opened for an unexpected reason, error=Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10669 "(null)" UserInfo={_LSLine=4141, _LSFunction=_LSOpenStuffCallLocal}"[image]

Comment: Where did you get the installation package? Make sure it's compatible with your CPU.